# How to see a list of SPSS macros presently defined

Tags: macros, spss

Does anyone know of a way to get a list of macros presently loaded to memory (i.e. the define-!enddefine command has been run)?
Also, is there a way to see the full macro definitions - from memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a list of already defined Macros use the following Syntax:

```
DISPLAY MACROS.
```

To my knowledge there is no way to get the macro definitions directly (unless you read the syntax files where they are defined).

Comment: Correct.  You can only refer to the defining syntax, and there is no way to see even the names of defined macros.  This is another reason for using Python programmability in place of macro.  You can, at least, run SET MPRINT ON to see the code generated when the macro is invoked.

Comment: @JKP, you say there is no way do see macro names, but actually @mirirai's `display macros` seems to work fine

Comment: I take it back.  You are right.  I forgot about DISPLAY MACROS.  it only shows you the names, though, not the definitions or the signatures.